# How to access ionic cordova-sqlite-storage ios database into xamarin ios

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, xamarin.ios, cordova-plugins

I have developing ios applications on ionic and xamarin forms and both applications are different. I have stored the user info in ionic by using Cordova-Sqlite-Storage. I want to access that database in xamarin ios application.

I have tried this, but the User table is not found.

```
var fileName = "databaseName"
var documentPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
var path = Path.Combine(documentPath, fileName);
var connection = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(path);
```

Can we access Ionic Cordova-Sqlite-database in xamarin ios application? Please give your valuable suggestions.

Comment: Your code looks no problem at all , as the error said , `the User table is not found` ,please attach this part of the code , try to figure out which line cause the error .

Comment: @ColeXia-MSFT, thanks for your reply. I have referred this [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-file#android-file-system-layout), the ios storage is private. So we cannot access the Cordova-SQLite-storage plugin database from other applications.